# How to connect to a SQL Server database from a connection string stored in a table ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection, sql-server-2014

I have a table called 'A' with these fields '{ id, Connection String}'

and In Sql Server, I want to excecute a command that connect to the first database in 'A' table from it's connection string and query it's table data.

Sudo code:  `select * from [db_connectionstring].dbo.mytable`

Is this achievable ?  I hop some one can help me here. :)

Comment: This is sort of like locking the key inside the chest and asking how to get in. You could do this but it would require having valid user credentials to first establish a connection and query the table. Then you could use the value from that table to create a new connection. All seems kind of silly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SQL Server can't connect to other SQL Servers via a connection string.   It can do it via Linked Servers, provided they are set up in advance.

Maybe it could be done in a CLR procedure.  Otherwise, what you are trying to do needs to be done in an external app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information in your table to generate and execute a

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql

Statement then use the linked server you have created, you would have to check if you have already created the linked server.

this is better done from your app and not SQL server.